# harcode Rows with union

Tags: plsql

I have a select query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address END) AS CHINESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address END) AS FRENCH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address END) AS PORTUGUESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address END) AS SPANISH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address END) AS KOREAN
FROM 
    table1;
```

The result is

```
CHINESE PORTUGUESE KOREAN SPANISH FRENCH  
  2  22 3 4 5
```

Now I want to add another row with hardcoded values

```
select 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address END) AS CHINESE,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address END) AS FRENCH,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address END) AS PORTUGUESE,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address END) AS SPANISH,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address END) AS KOREAN
FROM table1;
UNION
SELECT 30,40,50,60,70 from table 2;
```

It is not yielding results

I want the result like

```
CHINESE PORTUGUESE KOREAN SPANISH FRENCH  
row_1  2 2 1 1 1  
row_2  30 305 290 0 0  ( hardcoded values)
```

Comment: How can the result of your first query have 7 value columns (2, 22, 3, 4, 5, 32, 32)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not yielding results'? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: What would you want to happen if the calculated row is the same as the hardcoded row? Should two rows appear still, or just one? (I'm trying to work out here if you really need `UNION`, as that's a more expensive operation than `UNION ALL`)

Comment: @Pavel..I am not getting the desired result

Comment: @Boneist I need union because there are multiple select statements which I have not mentioned here. in case both yield same results still i need two rows to show the same

Comment: If you need `UNION` elsewhere, then fine, but to end up with two identical rows at the end, one of which is your hardcoded row, then you need `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
select 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address else null END) AS CHINESE,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address else null END) AS FRENCH,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address else null END) AS PORTUGUESE,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address else null END) AS SPANISH,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address else null END) AS KOREAN
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 30 AS CHINESE,40 AS FRENCH,50 AS PORTUGUESE,60 AS SPANISH,70  AS KOREAN from table2;
```

Comment: Well, probably not `from table2` as you might get *zillion* of rows as a result (depending on how many rows `table2` contains). A safer/better data source would be `dual`.

Comment: Thanks for the help..This works.. Only thing is how to get the row name such as row_1 and row_2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also include the text `row_1` and `row_2` in the results, you can add them as hardcoded text values:

```
SELECT
    'row_1' AS ROWNAME,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END) AS CHINESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END) AS FRENCH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END) AS PORTUGUESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END) AS SPANISH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END) AS KOREAN
  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT
    'row_2' AS ROWNAME,
    30 AS CHINESE,
    40 AS FRENCH,
    50 AS PORTUGUESE
    60 AS SPANISH,
    70 AS KOREAN
  FROM table2;
```

Based on your existing data, this will output:

```
ROWNAME CHINESE FRENCH PORTUGUESE SPANISH KOREAN
row_1   2       2      1          1       1  
row_2   30      40     50         60      70
```

Comment: yeah..correct..thanks that helps..another twist if you can help is after the union and the above desire result can I have the third row which adds the values..for example chinese as 32, french as 42 , prtuguese as 51, spanish as 61 and korean as 71..

Comment: @Nishu You can add the hardcodes to the first select statement
  `SELECT
    'Total' AS ROWNAME,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END)+30 AS CHINESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END)+40 AS FRENCH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END)+50 AS PORTUGUESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END)+60 AS SPANISH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address ELSE NULL END)+70 AS KOREAN`